# Smooth normals to avoid squares in shading

Tags: shaders, normals, bump

I am trying to make ripples using *Geometry Nodes* and I got some problem :

[image: Example of issue on normal map]

This is how the generated bump map looks. Is there a way to smooth that overlapping bump data ?

I use *Geometry Nodes* proximity to create round mask near object, then plugged it into a noise texture vector input in the shader editor.

[image: Node setup in shader editor]